# Using redirect in Vue/Nuxt Plugin

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

In my Vue/Nuxt application, I have a plugin with the following code:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';

axios.interceptors.response.use(res => {
  console.log('Interceptor response: ', res.data);

  return res;
},
err => {
    if (err.response.status === 401) {
      this.$store.dispatch(AUTH_LOGOUT);
      redirect('/');
    }
});

Vue.use(axios);
```

The problem is that both 'redirect' and 'this.$store' appear to be undefined. Can you help me with how I can use redirect or store inside this vue/nuxt plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [context](https://nuxtjs.org/api/context) variable.

Example:

`plugins/axios.js`

```js
import axios from 'axios'

export default function (context, inject) {
  axios.interceptors.response.use(res => {
    console.log('Interceptor response: ', res.data);
    return res;
  }, err => {
    if (err.response.status === 401) {
      context.redirect('/');
      context.store.dispatch(AUTH_LOGOUT);
    }
  });

  inject('axios', axios)
}
```

> [Inject in $root & context](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins#inject-in-root--context)

Comment: Thanks. Why did you do: inject('axios', axios)?

Comment: Also, I could use it this way: export default function ({ store, redirect }) . Is this alright?

Comment: Yes. For `inject` as show in the link I provided so you can use `$axios` from `context`, via `this` in Vue instances and via `this` in store actions/mutations.